# DBUM vs DBAT OIM Connector use cases

Tags: oim

I have following two quick questions:

For things like unlocking a DB user account, locking DB user account, resetting passwords DB user account password, in an Oracle DB using OIM should we use DBAT or DBUM or DBAT connector ?

Also can we configure both DBUM and DBAT connector in OIM to connect to the same target Oracle DB ?

Answer (score 0):

For user/account management you need DBUM connector. Yes, you can configure both connectors to point to the same DB